# How to debug revert transaction with truffle

Tags: debugging, solidity, truffle, revert

I want to simulate revert-error, launching tests of Solidity contract with Truffle, but I need to get input call data for simulating it in other project, which I got from debugger. How can I launch debug despite errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use revertedWith to simulate revert-error, in my case I revert if the user don't have enough tokens.

```
   it("Transfer token", async ()=> {
        await expect(instance.transfer.call(accounts[1],9999999999)).to.be.revertedWith("You dont have enough tokens")
      });
```